# Hashtag symbol in C++ macro expression

Tags: c++, macros, c++14

In the macro definition below, what does '#' symbol do? What is this syntax (#x) here?

```cpp
#define print(x) cout<<(#x)<<" : "<<x<<endl;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`#` is the stringify operator. It turns the macro argument `x` into a string literal.

I can see no reason for the extra parens, `#define print(x) cout << #x <<" : " << x << endl;` would work just as well. Even better would be `#define print(x) cout << #x <<" : " << (x) << endl;` because the second use of `x` might require parens to be parsed correctly.

Comment: Thank you @john for good explanation and suggestion